# dplyr programming: how to access columns of .x in map

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

Nesting a dataframe and transforming each tibble into an xts happens often enough to deserve its own function.

The input dataframe should be nested by nest_var, then each nested dataframe should be converted to an xts object order.by t_var

This is my attempt,

```
library(tidyverse)
library(purrr)
library(magrittr)
library(xts)
data("sample_matrix")
    df <- sample_matrix %>%
        as.data.frame() %>%
        rownames_to_column(var='dt') %>%
        gather(key=ohlc, value=val, -dt)

nest_xts <- function(df_in, nest_var, t_var) {
    require(rlang)
    nest_var <- enquo(nest_var)
    t_var <- enquo(t_var)

    df_in %>% group_by(!!nest_var) %>%
    nest() %>%
    mutate(data := map(data, ~xts(.x, order.by=.x[quo_name(t_var)])))
}
nest_xts(df, ohlc, dt)
```

but this is not accessing the columns of .x in the mutate, map combo on the last line.

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: order.by requires an appropriate time-based object.
```

Also tried changing the last line to

```
mutate(data := map(data, ~xts(.x, order.by=.x$!!t_var)))
```

but the function does not compile;

```
Error: unexpected '!' in:
"    nest() %>%
    mutate(data := map(data, ~xts(.x, order.by=.x$!"
> }
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
```

Comment: Do you have example data that causes the error you could post?

Comment: thanks, added an example from the sample_matrix included in xts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You achieved to access the column. But `tbl_df[colname]` isn't `vector` but `tbl_df`.

```
order.by = .x[quo_name(t_var)][[1]]
# or
order.by = pull(.x, quo_name(t_var))

# and (carelessly?)
df <- df %>% mutate(dt = as.Date(dt))
```

gives what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Below is just a simplified nesting approach. Not sure if it directly addresses your needs.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(purrr)
library(magrittr)
library(xts)
data("sample_matrix")
df <- sample_matrix %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  rownames_to_column(var='dt') %>%
  gather(key=ohlc, value=val, -dt)

nest_xts <- function(df_in, nest_var, t_var) {
  require(rlang)
  nest_var <- enquo(nest_var)
  t_var <- enquo(t_var)

  df_in %>% 
    group_by(!!nest_var) %>%
    summarize(data = list(xts(!!t_var, order.by=as.Date(dt))))
}
result <- nest_xts(df, ohlc, dt)
result
# A tibble: 4 x 2
# ohlc      data
# <chr>    <list>
#  1 Close <S3: xts>
#  2  High <S3: xts>
#  3   Low <S3: xts>
#  4  Open <S3: xts>
```